# ITextSharp Margin

Tags: vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2013, itext

I am working with itexsharp and I have problem because it does not assign the margin of the document
This is the code.

```
Dim pdfw As PdfWriter
    Dim documentoPDF As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 20, 20, 20, 20) 'Creamos el objeto documento PDF
    documentoPDF.SetMargins(0.0F, 0.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)

    pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documentoPDF, New FileStream(urlFija & "\" & "Manifiesto-" & Manifiesto & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
    documentoPDF.Open()


    documentoPDF.NewPage()
    Dim aTable = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(3)
    Dim Ancho0 As Single() = {0.75F, 1.45F, 0.75F}
    'aTable.DefaultCell.Border = BorderStyle.None

    Dim Imagen As iTextSharp.text.Image
    Imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path & "Ministerio-3.jpg")
    Imagen.ScalePercent(25)
    Imagen.SetAbsolutePosition(25.0F, 25.0F)

    Dim Img = New PdfPCell
    Img.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
    Img.AddElement(Imagen)

    aTable.AddCell(Img)

    Dim C1 = New PdfPCell(New Paragraph("Formato", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 13, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)))
    C1.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    C1.VerticalAlignment = 2
    C1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

    aTable.AddCell(C1)

    Dim C2 = New PdfPCell(New Paragraph("Prueba", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 7, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
    C2.HorizontalAlignment = 3
    C2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
    aTable.AddCell(C2)
    aTable.SetWidths(Ancho0)
documentoPDF.Add(aTable)
documentoPDF.AddAuthor(Session("IDUsuario").ToString)
    documentoPDF.AddTitle("Manifiesto")
    documentoPDF.AddCreationDate()
    documentoPDF.Close()
```

After this I added a table with the information, move me just the top margin

Comment: What does the broken English *After this I added a table with the information, move me just the top margin* mean? How are you adding the table? Are you aware that a table is centered and only takes 80% of the width unless you change the width percentage? You are leaving out the most important part of your code snippet and you're not telling us anything useful about the actual problem you experience.

Comment: sorry
I do not speak English. What happens is that I assign the margin to the sheet (as show it in the code), but does not take it, I need the right and the left margin is the minimum possible but it is not possible. working with tables to display information.

Comment: I see, you are yet another developer who didn't read the documentation. I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented, the width of a `PdfPTable` takes only 80% of the available width by default when you add it to a page (unless you define an absolute width instead of a relative width). It will be centered, so you will have a left and a right margin of 10% of the available width.

If you want the table to span 100%, you need to add this line:

```
aTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
```

Now the table will span the full width.